# Django URLs - make 'cleaner'?

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a django application, and I was wondering if there was a better way to display my URLS after submitting a GET request.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^reporting/$', ReportView.as_view(), name='report'),
]
```

When I got to localhost:8000/reporting which displays a form, and click on a radio button and submit, it takes me to:

```
http://localhost:8000/reporting/?run=2&submit=Search+for+run
```

I would prefer it if it was something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/reporting/run=2/
```

because this page displays another form, which I would like to 'add on' to this:

```
http://localhost:8000/reporting/run=2/choice=primary/
```

Is this possible - would I have to have several different URLS relating to different views?

Comment: Well this is the format of a `GET` request. You can however write more complex URL patterns and let JavaScript do som tricks to change the URL, but this makes it less flexible, an requires some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to mangle URLs like that (and I'd challenge the assertion that your way is "cleaner"), you could preserve the existing parameters by outputting hidden fields within the form which would then be sent along with the visible ones:

```
<form method="GET">
  {% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ value }}">
  {% endfor %}
  .. rest of form ..
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, I have ended up doing this! I guess there is no real need to have the URL in that string structure

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel's answer is correct.

But the answer of your question

`Is this possible - would I have to have several different URLS relating to different views?`

is also YES.

Your `ReportView` is kind of `ListView`. I guess it shows all list from `Report`.

Then you can make `DetailView` from Report - which shows one report object per page.

It should be like

`http://localhost:8000/reporting/2/`

And instead of `2`, you can add anything you want (Report's title, slug is find) - but it should be UNIQUE so I recommend `pk`(id) or `slug`.

For make `DetailView`, you have to make view (like `ReportDetailView`), add urls, and make templates for view.

You should check [django detailview docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for this I will look into this as I think it is exactly what I want!!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you! Happy hacking!